# Нейросеть Хопфилда

Tags: нейронные-сети

В процессе использования, сеть считает значения по формуле
*X(n+1)=F(W*X(n)+B).

Где X(n) X(n+1)предыдущее и следующее значение, F-функция активации сигмоид,W- матрица весов,B-смещения.
Вопрос в следующем:как выяснить чему равно B? Может быть есть какая-то формула для этого?

Answer (score 0):

Знаю только про смещение обычной сети(Хопфилда не изучал).Биасы(смещения) учавствуют так:

```
""" Получить вектор входов, сделать матричный продукт и матричный продукт пропустить через функцию активации"""

    # записать этот вектор в параметр слоя сети(hidden)
    def make_hidden(nn_params, objLay:Lay, inputs:list, debug):
        tmp_v = 0
        val = 0
        for row in range(objLay.out):
            for elem in range(objLay.in_):
                if nn_params.with_bias:
                   if elem==0:
                      tmp_v+=objLay.matrix[row][elem]
                   else:
                      tmp_v+=objLay.matrix[row][elem] *\
                             inputs[elem]
                else:
                    tmp_v+=objLay.matrix[row][elem] *\
                           inputs[elem]
            objLay.cost_signals[row] = tmp_v
            val = operations(nn_params.act_fu,tmp_v, 0, 0, 0, "", nn_params)
            objLay.hidden[row] = val
            tmp_v = 0
```